# Amazon iOS Mobile SDK v2 Create empty folder

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a question related with **Amazon iOS Mobile SDK v2**. I have a task to create an empty folder inside provided bucket. To create an empty folder I am using method:

```
- (void)createDirectory:(AWSS3Object *)directory inBucket:(AWSS3Bucket *)bucket success:(void (^)())success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSString *configurationKey = [NSString string];

    if (self.configurationType == AmazonServiceConfigurationTypeDefault)
    {
        configurationKey = S3ConfigurationKey;
    }

    else if (self.configurationType == AmazonServiceConfigurationTypeHUB)
    {
        configurationKey = S3HUBConfigurationKey;
    }

    else if (self.configurationType == AmazonServiceConfigurationTypeTemporary)
    {
        configurationKey = S3TemporaryConfigurationKey;
    }

    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 S3ForKey:configurationKey];

    AWSS3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];

    putObjectRequest.key = directory.key;
    putObjectRequest.bucket = bucket.name;
    putObjectRequest.body = [NSString string];

    [[s3 putObject:putObjectRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
    {
        if (task.error)
        {
            NSError *error = task.error;

            failure(error);
        }

        else
        {
            success();
        }

        return nil;
    }];
}
```

With this method I am always getting the error: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`.

My access and secure keys are correct.

From the previous experience, I was used to get this error because of incorrect parameters.

**My key:** `AWS iOS SDK v2 Test/test/`

**My bucket:** `abc-test`

Previously, when I was using AWS iOS Mobile SDK v1, practically the same code has been working like a charm.

Does anyone know, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this problem, The cause of problem is the trailing slash of the key value has been stripped by `NSURL.path` ,lead to an incorrect request signature error. We will fix the AWS Mobile SDK in future release. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it possible some how work around with this issue at the moment?

Comment: Also, can you predict the timing when current issue is possible to be fixed?

Comment: Hi @TomKortney , We've release AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.2.3 which solve this issue where an empty directory cannot be created, for more details, please refer to release notes: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/iOS/4731210461260864   Thanks.